# hostname in docker-compose.yml fails to be recognized on on mac (but works on linux)

Tags: macos, networking, docker

I am using the docker-compose 'recipe' below to bring up a container that runs a  component of the storm stream processing framework. I am finding that on Mac's
when i enter the container (once it is up and running via `docker exec -t -i <container-id> bash`)
and I do `ping storm-supervisor` I get the error 
'unknown host'. However, when i run the same docker-compose script on Linux
the host is recognized and ping succeeds.

The failure to resolve the host leads to problems with the Storm component... but what 
that component is doing can be ignored for this question. I'm pretty sure if I figured out
how to get the Mac's docker-compose behavior to match Linux's then I would have no problem.

I think i am experiencing the issue mentioned in this post:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-not-setting-hostname-when-network-mode-host/16728

```
version: '2'
services:
  supervisor:
    image: sunside/storm-supervisor
    container_name: storm-supervisor
    hostname: storm-supervisor
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - "LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost"
      - "NIMBUS_ADDRESS=localhost"
      - "NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT=49627"
      - "DRPC_PORT=49772"
      - "DRPCI_PORT=49773"
      - "ZOOKEEPER_ADDRESS=localhost"
      - "ZOOKEEPER_PORT=2181"
```

thanks in advance for any leads or tips !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"network_mode: host" will not work well on docker mac. I experienced the same issue where I had few of my containers in bridge network and the others in host network.
However, you can move all your containers to a custom bridge network. It solved for me.
You can edit your docker-compose.yml file to have a custom bridge network.

```
version: '2'
services:
  supervisor:
    image: sunside/storm-supervisor
    container_name: storm-supervisor
    hostname: storm-supervisor
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - "LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost"
      - "NIMBUS_ADDRESS=localhost"
      - "NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT=49627"
      - "DRPC_PORT=49772"
      - "DRPCI_PORT=49773"
      - "ZOOKEEPER_ADDRESS=localhost"
      - "ZOOKEEPER_PORT=2181"
    networks:
      - storm
networks:
  storm:
    external: true
```

Also, execute the below command to create the custom network.

```
docker network create storm
```

You can verify it by

```
docker network ls
```

Hope it helped.